# How to plot multiple points using QCustomPlot QT5?

Tags: c++, qt, plot, qcustomplot

Here are some example points:

```
(1,1),(2,3),(3,1),(4,2),(1,5),(3,4)
```

I want to plot these points with a line in turn, I've added them into the vector `x` and `y`. Then, `setData(x,y)` was performed.
However, the `QCustomPlot` seems like can only plot points by the order of `x` axis. 
I noticed the points were sorted automatically by the `setData(x,y)`.

How can I do to plot these points by the original order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is using [`QCPCurve`](http://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/classQCPCurve.html) instead of Graph.

Define:

```
QCPCurve *newCurve;
```

And initiate it by doing:

```
this->newCurve = new QCPCurve(ui->customPlot->xAxis, ui->customPlot->yAxis);
ui->customPlot->addPlottable(this->newCurve);
```

Then you can use it the same way as you did with the Graph:

```
QVector<double> x, y;
//...
this->newCurve->setData(x, y);
```

See also this example: [Parametric Curves Demo](http://qcustomplot.com/index.php/demos/parametriccurvesdemo).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really helps!

Comment: @wuhanmoon If this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the *V* mark next to it. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Based on A. Sarid’ help, I found the usage of QCPCurve in the demos(11).
The difference between QCPCurve and QCPGraph is that one x can correspond to different y with QCPCurve.
So, just add the code:

QCPCurve *newCurve = new QCPCurve(ui->customPlot->xAxis, ui->customPlot->yAxis);
newCurve->setData(x,y);

Thanks to A. Sarid again!